# Android App is not listed in Market search

Tags: android, list, search, google-play

I have recently uploaded a few more Go SMS Pro themes but they don't show up in the market search. My older themes do show up. In theory there should not be any difference between the older ones and the new ones except for the name of the package and the changes I made in colors/pictures etc. They are in the market, one can find them by linking directly. Developer console states everything is ok and available to 694 devices. As an example I will give the direct link to my Free halloween theme.

[Free Halloween Theme](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms.ry4ndroid.halloween)

Since I did not change anything that should influence the visibility to the filters or something I have no clue as of why these last 3 themes don't show up.

Update, It does show up when I change the filter to popularity! But not when it is filtered on relevance.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: your apps are getting listed when searched like 'gosmspro' from HTC desire or search using the developer name. I got the app listed.

Comment: Hello Basil, Thank you for your information. Can you please confirm this Halloween theme is listed? I should have about 9 apps listed but not the Halloween (paid/unpaid) and the purple theme. Thank you so much for assisting. Use search in market and than ry4ndroid halloween.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been recognised by google and in my case it has been fixed! Question answered.

For those of you still having the problem, check your developer console for messages and also, if your apps are also not listed when you change the filter to popularity instead of relevance you most likely have a different problem.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

From the android developers console:

> **25 October 2011 - Recently published apps not appearing in Android Market**
>
> We're aware of reports from some developers that apps recently published don't appear in Android Market. This issue is impacting both app searches and when viewing a developer's app catalog on both mobile devices and the web view of Android Market. We're investigating this issue and are striving to resolve it as soon as possible. No action is needed on your part at this time. Please check back here for updates
>
> [Learn More](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1717031)